# No command 'update' found, what should I use instead?

Tags: encryption, command-line

I had a problem while booting my PC, the same as [this one](http://punygeek.blogspot.com.ar/2012/10/ubuntu-1204-how-to-solve-disk-drive-for.html): "The disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present" error at boot.

I tried with these instructions, but I'm stuck at the 7th step:

> update **/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume** with the new UUID
>
> ex.
>   RESUME=UUID=**06a9be15-d05b-466d-bfe3-a086bb9cdba0**

I typed

```
update /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume UUID=d6cc5d42-0375-48a2-b4e1-a3a52ad25c7a
```

But I get

```
No command 'update' found, did you mean:
 Command 'pupdate' from package 'pbuilder-scripts' (universe)
 Command 'lupdate' from package 'qt4-linguist-tools' (main)
 Command 'uupdate' from package 'devscripts' (main)
 Command 'xupdate' from package 'libxml-xupdate-libxml-perl' (universe)
update: command not found
```

Any ideas about how to solve it?

P.S.: I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: You are supposed to create or edit a file. Open it with a text editor and paste or replace the UUID=... text.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a command. You have to edit the **/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume** file and replace the UUID (the big string with letters, numbers and "-") with the one you got in the previous step.

Comment: After editing that file you probably have to run `update-initramfs -u -k all` to make your changes work.